# Use of a package manager with Domino and locations of node modules

Tags: git, xpages, lotus-notes, yarnpkg, package-managers

I am considering using a package manager to avoid registration of external resources in GIT. But I wonder how I should setup my projects?

Nowadays in GIT I have my NSF code registrered in an ODP folder e.g. projectx\ODP\ e.g. projectx\OODP\WebContent\DataTables

When I run a package manager I notice that the resources are stored in the folder that contains the package.json file in folder nodes_modules.

Does this mean that I should store the package.json file in the WebContent folder or can I specify in the package file where the modules should be installed?

To avoid the files are registered for source control in GIT I should register them in the .gitignore file and state ODP\WebContent* but this would also keep the package.json file from source control which I would like to have under source control.

All confusing to me.

Can someone tell me how you have setup your workspace for XPages development using a package manager and GIT?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the node_modules, or waht are you using them for?
Anyway, you could just add ODP\WebContent\node_modules to your  .gitignore file.

Comment: the node modules are the plugins I use for in my project e.g. datatables, fontawesome but to be available on the Domino webserver they need to reside in the WebContent folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the installation directory in yarn https://www.caxy.com/blog/how-set-custom-location-nodemodules-path-yarn

Answer (score 5):

You need to take a step back and check what you want to achieve:

- Your Domino project is a BACKEND project
- The JavaScript you write is a FRONTEND project (in case it's not: there is no place for a NodeJS application in your WebContent project)
- `node_modules` for frontend project is a design time need, not a runtime need
- You want to use something like [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/), [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/), [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) to bundle your front-end. Most CLI tools use one of them
- These bundlers allow you to specify an output directory. Use `WebContent` for that
- Keep the front-end project in a separate tree

```
/projectx/odp/...
/projectx/frontend/...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hello Stephan, so what you are suggesting is to use one of the tools you mention to move the files downloaded into the node_modules directory to the webcontent directory?

Comment: What I'm trying to say: if you design a FRONTEND app, the result of any of these tools would be an app that doesn't rely on any node_modules directory. Typically the output directory is something like `/dist` which you would reconfigure to point to webcontent. Front-end apps don't use node_modules at runtime

Comment: oh but I am using the modules in my xpages application

Comment: Calling from front-end code? Still a package will help